# Mongoose database modeling

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose as well as nosql. I am designing a database which will contain a list of people and each person could have multiple skills - like C, Java, Python. Further the person would have been using the particular skill since a particular time - eg. Since 2010.

I have created a personSchema and a skillSchema. I am not able to figure how to add the "Since" **as the since is specific to a person but is also for a particular skill.**

I really need the skill to be a separate schema as the list of skills would be used elsewhere.

```
 let personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true, dropDups: true},
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  age: Number
  mobile: [Number],
  skills: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Skill'}]
});

let skillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  skillName: String  
});
```

Now where to store "since"?
E.g Tom is working on C++ since 2010 - The 2010 is related to both Tom and C++

Comment: Maybe I should add "since" to the "skills" in the personSchema. What would be the syntax to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
skills : [
         {
          skill : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Skill'}
          since : Number
         }]
```

Adding 'Since' this way will make more sense as each skill reference will have its since value with it.

Hope it helps.